# Using NodeJS to add pre-existing YouTube videos to a YouTube channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I was wondering if there might be a module/script sample that demonstrates how to programmatically add an already-existing YouTube video to my own YouTube channel?

I was imagining a scenario where folks could submit their YouTube videos and - if approved - have them automatically added to a channel? Ideally this would be handled with NodeJS.

Comment: It is not possible to change a video's owner (i.e. move it to another channel). The only thing you can do with already existing videos from other channels is to add them to a playlist of your channel.

Comment: But it should be possible to let a user upload a private video to your channel, which you can later publish if you like.

Comment: Thanks @paolo! That definitely answers my question.

Comment: Actually, this is incorrect; you cannot let users upload videos to your channel. All uploads through the API happen through oAuth2 authentication, meaning they can only upload to their own channel. Then, as suggested in the first comment, you can programmatically add those videos to a playlist in your channel.